# Algorithm of number conversion？

Tags: java, algorithm, binary, numbers, decimal

```
public static String DeciToBin(int i)
{
    String zero="0";
    String one="1";
    String str = "";
    if(i==0)
    {
        return zero;
    }
    if(i==1)
    {
        return one;
    }
    for(;i<2;i/=2)
    {
        if(i%2==1)
        {
            str= one+str;
        }
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            str=zero+str;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

It turned out nothing when i is bigger than 1. There's no error or caution in these lines. What did I miss?

Comment: Assuming `i` isn't negative, if `i != 0` and `i != 1`, then `i < 2` is immediately false. Step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: Hint: for loop proceeds only if the condition (in your case `i<2`) is satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test whether `i>0` or not not stop if you get a number of 2 or more.

You can simplify this a lot.

```
public static String deciToBin(int i) {
    String str = "";
    do {
        str = (i & 1) + str;
        i >>>= 1;
    } while (i != 0);
    return str;
}
```

Even better would be to use StringBuilder

```
public static String deciToBin(int i) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    do {
        str.append(i & 1);
        i >>>= 1;
    } while (i != 0);
    return str.reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method in java to convert int to binary.

```
Integer.toBinaryString(a);
```

You can use the following method in java to convert int to any base

```
Integer.toString(Number, Base);
```